# Grouping Sets possibly dropping a set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the below columns:

```
 manufact nameplat model modelyea newseg newsubseg region sales
bmw        bmw    230I   2016     x      y         west   13
bmw        bmw    230I   2017     x      q         west   20
bmw        bmw    230I   2018     x      r         south  12
```

I need to perform aggregation across all the levels for many clients with different join conditions. Currently, I have a dynamic SQL which does the aggregation for each level separately, constructs the group by and joins dynamically since a lot of other factors in play here. The process is very slow and is running for hours.

I was looking at grouping sets to do the same. While it is definitely faster, it is not aggregating some of the sets.

The issue is that the query is not printing out the results for this set:

```
(period,newseg,modelyea,map_region.region)
```

The `grouping_id(period,newseg,modelyea,map_region.region)` has a value.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

```
select period
,case  when GROUPING_ID(period,manufact,nameplat,dma.model,newsegment,newsubseg,modelyea,map_region.region) > 0 AND ( GROUPING_ID(period,manufact,nameplat,newsegment,newsubseg,modelyea,map_region.Region) = 32 OR GROUPING_ID(period,manufact,nameplat,newsegment,newsubseg,modelyea,map_region.Region) = 34) then 'Nameplate' 
when GROUPING_ID(period,manufact,nameplat,dma.model,newsegment,newsubseg,modelyea,map_region.region) = 0 OR GROUPING_ID(period,manufact,nameplat,dma.model,newsegment,newsubseg,modelyea,map_region.region) = 2 then 'Model'
when (GROUPING_ID(period,manufact,nameplat,dma.model,newsegment,newsubseg,modelyea,map_region.region) > 0 AND GROUPING_ID(period,manufact,nameplat,dma.model,newsegment,newsubseg,modelyea,map_region.region) > 0 AND GROUPING_ID(period,manufact,modelyea,map_region.region) = 0 ) OR (GROUPING_ID(period,manufact,nameplat,dma.model,newsegment,newsubseg,modelyea,map_region.region) > 0 AND GROUPING_ID(period,manufact,nameplat,dma.model,newsegment,newsubseg,modelyea,map_region.region) > 0 AND GROUPING_ID(period,manufact,modelyea,map_region.region) > 0 ) then 'Manufacturer' 
else 'N/A' end as Granularity 
,isnull(manufact,'N/A') as manufact
,isnull(nameplat,'N/A') as nameplat
,isnull(dma.model,'N/A') as model
,isnull(dma.newsegment,'N/A') as seg1
,isnull(dma.newsubseg,'N/A') as seg2
,isnull(modelyea,'All') as modelyea
,map_region.region
,GROUPING_ID(period,manufact,nameplat,dma.model,newsegment,newsubseg,modelyea,map_region.region) as Grouping_ID_Model
,GROUPING_ID(period,manufact,nameplat,newseg,newsubseg,modelyea,map_region.Region) as GID_Nameplate
,GROUPING_ID(period,manufact,modelyea,map_region.region) as GID_Manu
,GROUPING_ID(period,newseg,modelyea,map_region.region) as GID_Seg
,sum(sales) as sales
from dma
join region_map map_region ON dma.dma = map_region.dma
where monthofs= 201801
and dma.dma = map_region.dma
and dma.model = '230I'
group by grouping sets (
(period,manufact,nameplat,dma.model,newsegment,newsubseg,modelyea,map_region.region) --model,modelyea
,(period,manufact,nameplat,dma.model,newsegment,newsubseg,map_region.region) --model all MY
,(period,nameplat,superseg,newsegment,newsubseg,modelyea,map_region.region) --nameplat,modelyea
,(period,nameplat,superseg,newsegment,newsubseg,map_region.region) -- nameplat all MY
,(period,manufact,modelyea,map_region.region) --manufact modelyea
,(period,manufact,map_region.region) --manufact all my
,(period,newsegment,modelyea,map_region.region) --segment modelyea
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only place in your SQL with an identifier 'newseg' is in that grouping_ids for 'GID_Nameplate' and 'GID_Seg'.  Should that be 'newsegment'?

Comment: thanks for responding. it is newsegment. was trying to trim for the posting here. but basically the same column